# How to add "plpgsql_check" Postgres extension in Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am creating a function in Amazon RDS and it is giving below error:

Extension "plpgsql_check" is not supported by Amazon RDS.

When i check the amzon documentation, plpgsql_check is not there in the list of allowed extensions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html

Is there any work around for this extension which we can add in Amazon RDS ?

Comment: You can only install the extensions in the allowed extensions list and trusted extensions.